# Application hanging on Control.Invoke except when debugging

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, deadlock

I have my main form kicking off some background work using `Delegate.BeginInvoke` and within those delegates I am adding some rows to be displayed on a `DataGridView` on my main form. I have a backing dataset and a `BindingSource` attached to that, which I use as the source for my `DataGridView`.

Whenever I add a row, I do this:

```
ResultsDataTable.AddResultsRow(row);
RefreshDataGridView();
```

Where `RefreshDataGridView()` looks like this:

```
private void RefreshDataGridView()
{
  if(InvokeRequired)
  {
    //I have tried dgvResults.Invoke() as well
    dgvResults.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => RefreshDataGridView()));
  }
  else
  {
    dgvResults.Refresh(); //this is where it hangs
    dgvResults.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgvResults.Rows.Count - 1;
  }
}
```

It works well, when I add a new row it displays instantly and scrolls (despite my scrollbar not being drawn correctly but I can live with that) as expected, but only when I run the app through the debugger. When I start it without debugging, the application hangs whenever a row is added and it actually needs to scroll.

I've built the application in debug mode and run it without debugging, then let it get to the point where it hangs and attached the debugger to the process to see where it is happening (see comment in code above).

I know this is happening because my main thread is waiting for something but I have no clue what it is waiting for or how to find out.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Update: I started it without debugging then attached the debugger again, and found that the main thread is getting stuck updating a control, but I can't figure out which one.

Update 2: I got rid of the refresh and now it doesn't hang when adding the new row, but I can't resize my form at all without it hanging.

Update 3: It seemed to be hanging while trying to update the scrollbars of the data grid, so I encapsulated it in a panel and gave that scrollbars instead. With a bit of hacking to get the data grid to dynamically size itself based on the data it contains, it's a bit glitchy but no more deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You mentioned that your DataGridView has a bindingsource attached to it. If you are doing something to your source, then you are affecting the DataGridView. You will need to place that line of code that is modifying the source inside the BeginInvoke statement. Once I did that, the issue is gone.